# require vs require_once PDO connection -- Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I was getting this Fatal error at the bottom of the page and didn't see it right away.  The error was pointing to a variable, the $sql, an SQL string, which is supposed to be an SQL string.   The code was "`$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);`". It seemed to work right, accessing the database and retrieving the correct information.  I had used this code before earlier on another page creating a new PDO connection.  Finally, after reading one of the comments on this error which I can't find again, I decided to try changing **require_once()** to **require()**.  And it worked.  Thank you whoever.

My guess is I needed to create a new PDO connection to use this new prepare.  I read that PHP closes the connection when the script is finished running.    I believe the prepare($sql), wasn't accepted not because it was a string, but because of some other problem connected with the old class somehow or another function named prepare.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask the question.

I think that you are using old way of avoiding code dublication.

Did you read documentation about [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)? You creating PDO object in external file. So, if you use require it would created every time. If you use require_once it would created only once.